# How to pass parameters/values to the pytest's fixture function from the test methods?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-fixtures

There are some variables defined in the test methods whose value I want to use in the setup fixture I have created, to elaborate it more, following is the problem:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture_method():
  ....
  ....

  **print(variable_from_test_method)**

  ....
  ....
  

def test_case():

 variable_from_test_method = 'This is my variable's value which I want to pass to fixture'
```

What I want to achieve is that I want to use the variable named 'variable_from_test_method ' defined in my test method named 'test_case' into my fixure named 'fixture_method'.

I was searching for some solution by using 'request' object but unable to understand how I can bring it into use.

Comment: And where is the fixture used?

Comment: I would recommend rethinking your approach. The setup fixtures get called before any test function is executed.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano the fixture would be used for that mentioned test method

Comment: @TeejayBruno I too have the same understanding, however the cucumber allows the 'context' object with the help of which we can use the attributes from the test functions into the functions that would be running before the test function. Hence I thought something similar would be available in pytest as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the `fixture` runs before the test. You can define it in the `fixture` and pass it to the test using `return`

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture_method():
    variable = 'This is my variable'
    return variable


def test_case(fixture_method):
    variable = fixture_method
    print(variable) # 'This is my variable'
```

Comment: Yes, but what I want to achieve is exactly the opposite of it

Comment: @Sanket as I wrote in the answer, you can't.

Comment: yep, thank you for the help!